# AzCopy - breaks on location with $ (dollar sign)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Goal is to copy straight into my blob container named "$web".

Problem is, dollar signs seem to break AzCopy's location parsing...

```
AzCopy.exe /Source:"C:\temp\" /Dest:"https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/$web" /DestKey:"..." /SetContentType /V

Invalid location 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/$web', address could not be parsed.
```

I don't get to choose the container name. Escaping the $, aka

```
 \$
```

didn't work.

How can I workaround this? Insights appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try something for me please? Instead of using `$web` container, can you try with `$root` container? The reason I ask this is to ascertain if the issue is with `$` sign in the blob container name or with `$web` as blob container name. `$web` is relatively new and it is quite possible that the Storage SDK used by AzCopy has not been updated to handle this.

Comment: If I drop the $web from the end, AzCopy works fine and the files end up in $root.

Comment: I'm trying to build a release task inside VSTS. It's a shame $web doesn't work yet, it's blocking me from what looks like an otherwise useful static website feature.

Comment: It would be worth retrying with AzCopy 10.3.2. We did a lot of work on handling of special characters, although I haven't personally tried the example you mention.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that John. While I've migrated to the Azure CLI these days others should benefit from your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To future readers who may be tempted to use pre-baked VSTS tasks like **File Copy** (which uses AzCopy under the hood), I recommend considering the **Azure CLI**  task instead, e.g.

`az storage blob upload-batch --account-name myAccountName --source mySource -d $web`

My client wasn't willing to wait for a schedule they didn't control so switching to the CLI path moved our dependency one level upstream & removed having to wait on the VSTS release cadence (looks like ~6 weeks this time).

Thanks Jerry for posting back, kudos! In my VSTS I see File Copy v2.0 Preview seems to be available and ostensibly fixes this issue. Static website hosting direct from Azure storage is a nice feature and I'm happy Azure offers it.

*(I hope in the future MS may be able to improve cross-org communication so savvy users keen to checkout new feature releases can have a more consistent experience across all the public-facing surface area.)*

Answer (score 2):

@Gaurav has pointed out the problem. For now Azcopy can only recognize the dollar sign with `$root` container. Also test in powershell, no breaking, but files are just uploaded to `$root` despite the name after `$`.

The new feature generating this `$web` container--[Static website hosting for Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-storage-static-web-hosting-public-preview/) has just released. It may take time for Azcopy to catch up the change.

Have opened [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/133), you can subscribe it for progress.

**Update**

Latest v7.3.0 Azcopy has supported this feature, and for VSTS users, Azure File Copy v2 task(2.0.7) is working with this latest version as well.

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue Jerry -- I posted some more details there.

Comment: @paws This could be fixed in new version azcopy, which is also available for VSTS users. Could you accept my answer to close this question?

Comment: Thanks Jerry for posting back.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a viable workaround suggesting using `az storage blob upload-batch` but the blob destination argument `$web` needs to be single quoted to work in PowerShell. Otherwise PowerShell will refer to a variable with the name "web"

E.g. Upload the current directory: `az storage blob upload-batch --account-name myaccountname --source . -d '$web'`

Answer (score 0):

the dollar sign works fine if you execute azcopy via cmd. if you use powershell, you have to escape the $ sign with `

so instead of:

```
azcopy list "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/$web?..."
# or
azcopy copy "c:\temp" "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/$web?..."
```

use:

```
azcopy list "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/`$web?..."
# or
azcopy "c:\temp" "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/`$web?..."
```

btw.: I received the following errors when I did not escape the dollar sign:

```
failed to traverse container: cannot list files due to reason -> github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob.newStorageError, /home/vsts/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.15.0/azblob/zc_storage_error.go:42
===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=OutOfRangeInput) =====
Description=The specified resource name length is not within the permissible limits.
```